# How to extract pages of information using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I'm having trouble capturing the contents of "name": he often appears before "pluralName" other later. What better way of doing this? (best way in terms of performance). Thank you for your help!

**Note:** I am using python

The chunk of the page that has the information I need:

```
{"count":0,"items":[]},"shortUrl":"http:\/\/4sq.com\/11nP13T","likes":{"count":22,"groups":[{"type":"others","count":22,"items":[]}],"summary":"22 Likes"},"ratingColor":"FF9600","id":"5172311be4b0ecc0a12a9953","canonicalPath":"\/v\/kee-hiong-klang-bak-kut-teh\/5172311be4b0ecc0a12a9953","canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/v\/kee-hiong-klang-bak-kut-teh\/5172311be4b0ecc0a12a9953","rating":5.3,"categories":[**{"pluralName":"Chinese Restaurants","name":"Chinese Restaurant",**"icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/asian_","mapPrefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_map\/food\/chinese","suffix":".png"},"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d145941735","shortName":"Chinese","primary":true},{"pluralName":"Asian Restaurants","name":"Asian Restaurant","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/asian_","mapPrefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_map\/food\/asian","suffix":".png"},"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d142941735","shortName":"Asian"}],"createdAt":1366438171,"tips":{"count":25,"groups":[{"count":25,"items":[{"logView":true,"text":"Portion is quite small and expensive. Service attitude is so so. The BKT taste is not my preference.One of the up car restaurants in SS2 which I'll never go back again. ðŸ‘Ž","likes":{"count":1,"groups":[{"type":"others","count":1,"items":[{"photo":{"prefix":"https:\/\/irs0.4sqi.net\/img\/user\/","suffix":"\/43964080-5LYADRF2EEP2RWPL.jpg"},"lastName":".w","firstName":"Jackie","id":"43964080","canonicalPath":"\/user\/43964080","canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/user\/43964080","gender":"female"}]}],"summary":"1 like"},"id":"541c2b73498eb0cfe1f76b9e","canonicalPath":"\/item\/541c2b73498eb0cfe1f76b9e","canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/item\/541c2b73498eb0cfe1f76b9e","createdAt":1.411132275E9,"todo":{"count":0},"user":{"photo":{"prefix":"https:\/\/irs1.4sqi.net\/img\/user\/","suffix":"\/5765949-NW4BAJWFBCVLRR1M.jpg"}
```

Comment: What do you need to match exactly?

Comment: Could you provide the expected output

Comment: I want match in this example "Asian Restaurant", But, I will run to other pages that have different values for the tag "name":

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:"pluralName":"[^"]*","name":"([^"]*))|(?:"name":"([^"]*)","pluralName")
```

Try this with `re.findall`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/4

```
print re.findall(r'(?:"pluralName":"[^"]*","name":"([^"]*))|(?:"name":"([^"]*)","pluralName")',test_str)
```

Comment: Thank you, had more of a result as output, but it is easier to work with these results.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regexp at all.

Instead, use a JSON parser, and access the resulting object. That is much more robust.

```
import json # part of python
o = json.loads(str)
```

Comment: Great answer! It might be clearer why this answer is better if you show an example of how to use `o`. Maybe even in the context of the posted question.

Comment: The JSON fragment he shared is FUBAR, broken beyond repair.